# Bind complex data and get selected item of a multiple selection

Tags: angularjs

When I click a button and get the selected schoolclass via:

`$scope.selectedSchoolclasses[0]` then there is only the schoolclass `schoolclassNumber` like "7a" but not the Id property.

Why is that? The bound schoolclasses array and its item have Id and schoolclassNumber properties.

**Controller**

```
$scope.schoolclasses = schoolclasses;
 $scope.selectedSchoolclasses = [];
```

**Html**

```
 <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select size="5" class="form-control control-label col-sm-6" multiple ng-model="selectedSchoolclasses">
        <option class="co-sm-6" ng-repeat="s in schoolclasses">
            {{s.schoolclassNumber}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to store instances of objects, you need to use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```
<select size="5" 
        class="form-control control-label col-sm-6" 
        multiple 
        ng-model="selectedSchoolclasses" 
        ng-options="s.schoolclassNumber for s in schoolclasses">
</select>
```

> In many cases, ngRepeat can be used on `<option>` elements instead of ngOptions to achieve a similar result. However, ngOptions provides some benefits such as reducing memory and increasing speed by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance, as well as providing more flexibility in how the `<select>`'s model is assigned via the select as part of the comprehension expression. **ngOptions should be used when the `<select>` model needs to be bound to a non-string value**. This is because an option element can only be bound to string values at present.

(emphasis mine)